# A variable is the same after the for loop and is different in another for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have been getting this error that returns a link(good one) after the for loop and then when I put the link variables inside a for link in links loop it returns a different one. This is my code:

```
links=[]
def Start():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Tera max/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win32/87.0.4280.88/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get('https://instagram.com/')
    sleep(2)
    driver.maximize_window()
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button').click()
    sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]").click()
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{}/'.format("messi"))
    sleep(2)
    links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

    def condition(link):
        return '.com/p/' in link.get_attribute('href')
    valid_links = list(filter(condition,links))

    for i in range(5):
        link = valid_links[i].get_attribute('href')
        if link not in links:
            links.append(link)
    print(link)

    for link in links:
        print(link)
        driver.get(link)
```

Here is the out put of printing the first link then the second one:

```
#first
https://www.instagram.com/p/CKMR3lMAD8O/
#second
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="664522e3bb5f9a9527be40d5e34b79d6", element="4a0d1327-fd66-40ff-a622-55da864e9d14")>
```

Comment: Your `if link not in links: links.append(link)` makes totally no sense as you iterate over `valid_links` that you got from `links`! Simply put, `valid_links` is sub-list of `links` and so it cannot contain elements that are not present in `links`

Answer (score 1):

print `links` and you'll see that the first `link` is the **last** element of `links`, while your second print is the **first** element of links.

I've reduced your code to demonstrate it more clearly:

```
links = []
for i in range(5):
    link = i
    links.append(i)
print(link)

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
4 # < your first print
0 # The follow-up prints from the loop
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have been trying to solve for three days .

Answer (score 1):

you are reusing `links` without emptying them first. look at this line:

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

and later at this line

```
links.append(link)
```

so now links contains BOTH types of items. Either make a new list or do `links.clear()` before your `for i` loop